# With CUDA 8 + gcc 5, unordered_map emplace with string key fails to compile

Tags: cuda, compatibility, factory, abi, emplace

Consider the following code:

```
#include <string>
#include <unordered_map>

int main()
{
    std::string s("hello");
    std::unordered_map<std::string, int> map;
    map.emplace(s, 123);
    return 0;
}
```

This builds fine with:

- GCC 4.9.3 , no CUDA
- GCC 5.3.1 , no CUDA
- GCC 4.9.3 via CUDA 7.5 (with file extension .cu)
- GCC 4.9.3 via CUDA 8 RC (with file extension .cu)

but **fails to compile** with GCC 5.3.1 via CUDA 8 RC.

The error I get is:

```
/usr/include/c++/5/bits/hashtable.h(1526): error: no instance of overloaded function "std::forward" matches the argument list
            argument types are: (std::__cxx11::string)
          detected during:
            instantiation of "std::pair<std::_Hashtable<_Key, _Value, _Alloc, _ExtractKey, _Equal, _H1, _H2, _Hash, _RehashPolicy, _Traits>::iterator, __nv_bool> std::_Hashtable<_Key, _Value, _Alloc, _ExtractKey, _Equal, _H1, _H2, _Hash, _RehashPolicy, _Traits>::_M_emplace(std::true_type, _Args &&) [with _Key=std::__cxx11::string, _Value=std::pair<const std::__cxx11::string, int>, _Alloc=std::allocator<std::pair<const std::__cxx11::string, int>>, _ExtractKey=std::__detail::_Select1st, _Equal=std::equal_to<std::__cxx11::string>, _H1=std::hash<std::__cxx11::string>, _H2=std::__detail::_Mod_range_hashing, _Hash=std::__detail::_Default_ranged_hash, _RehashPolicy=std::__detail::_Prime_rehash_policy, _Traits=std::__umap_traits<true>, _Args=<std::__cxx11::string &, int>]" 
(726): here
            instantiation of "std::_Hashtable<_Key, _Value, _Alloc, _ExtractKey, _Equal, _H1, _H2, _Hash, _RehashPolicy, _Traits>::__ireturn_type std::_Hashtable<_Key, _Value, _Alloc, _ExtractKey, _Equal, _H1, _H2, _Hash, _RehashPolicy, _Traits>::emplace(_Args &&...) [with _Key=std::__cxx11::string, _Value=std::pair<const std::__cxx11::string, int>, _Alloc=std::allocator<std::pair<const std::__cxx11::string, int>>, _ExtractKey=std::__detail::_Select1st, _Equal=std::equal_to<std::__cxx11::string>, _H1=std::hash<std::__cxx11::string>, _H2=std::__detail::_Mod_range_hashing, _Hash=std::__detail::_Default_ranged_hash, _RehashPolicy=std::__detail::_Prime_rehash_policy, _Traits=std::__umap_traits<true>, _Args=<std::__cxx11::string &, int>]" 
/usr/include/c++/5/bits/unordered_map.h(380): here
            instantiation of "std::pair<std::unordered_map<_Key, _Tp, _Hash, _Pred, _Alloc>::iterator, __nv_bool> std::unordered_map<_Key, _Tp, _Hash, _Pred, _Alloc>::emplace(_Args &&...) [with _Key=std::__cxx11::string, _Tp=int, _Hash=std::hash<std::__cxx11::string>, _Pred=std::equal_to<std::__cxx11::string>, _Alloc=std::allocator<std::pair<const std::__cxx11::string, int>>, _Args=<std::__cxx11::string &, int>]" 
a.cu(8): here

1 error detected in the compilation of "/tmp/tmpxft_00003494_00000000-9_a.cpp1.ii".
```

Is this a CUDA bug? If not, why would this be happening?

Comment: Is there an actual question here somewhere? This reads like a bug report, not like a question. I suspect it should be the former, rather than the latter.

Comment: Finally a proper MCVE.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is a CUDA bug:

I cross-posted this question to devtalk.nvidia.com , and was directed to file an official bug report. I then filed [CUDA bug 1774129](https://partners.nvidia.com/bug/viewbug/1774129) (login may be required).

nVIDIA developer Kevin Kang has confirmed the bug yesterday, saying:

> Hi, We have reproduced this issue locally, and our developers in compiler team are working on a fix for this issue actively. We'll keep you posted here once the further information becomes available.

When they fix it I'll edit this answer.

**Edit:** It's been fixed! ... but not on CUDA 8.0 RC of course. I suppose/hope this fix makes it into CUDA 8 final.